# How to generate a safe custom HTML error code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to set a Response.StatusCode to show a custom html page to tell the user that there is a license issue, so is there a base number that I can use?  I will then use custom errors to show the error page I want.

I know there was something in VB that allowed you to get a starting number for custom errors, then you just added a number to it (so the start would be say 500, so you could use 501 etc.)

Comment: what kind of license issues are you talking about?

Comment: The license issue is on a product that feeds data into my REST Service, so it's checking if the website has a valid license, if so the web site provides data

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what you need. Hope it helps you. [Click here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Comment: Yep seen that page, what I'm looking for is a safe number to use for my custom error (like 700 or above)?

Comment: You can also use custom codes in the range 4xx or 5xx. Just read and follow the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6). I would prefer a 4xx code since the client is requesting a page for which he has no authorization.

Comment: Thanks Alex B, I think that's the best I'm going to get.